# Error in if statement for setting balance

Tags: javascript

Am getting an if statement error, but can't figure it out. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```
var balance = 20.97;

if (balance < 10.00 ) {
    // console.log() the balance minus 5 dollars
    console.log("Your balance is (balance - 5.00).");
} else {
    // Just console.log() the balance
    console.log("Your balance is (balance).");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just printing a string. Placeholdering works like this:

```
console.log('Your balance is %s.', balance - 5.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log("Your balance is (balance - 5.00).");
```

should be

```
console.log("Your balance is %s.", (balance - 5.00));
```

The former will just say "Your balance is (balance - 5.00)" because JavaScript does not treat words like "balance" as variable references when they appear inside a string literal.

In the second, the message format string is distinct from the expression you want to display, and `console.log` replaces `%s` sequences with the other arguments.